# Mathematical difficulties

Tags: c, math

New guy here, and feeling like a bit of a dumbass, to be honest.

Basically, I am at university and one of my modules is Introduction to Programming (learning C). I really enjoy learning the programming and really want to take that further; however, I am really struggling with the math/logic. For example, each week we get these small tests which I have been doing OK on - unless they involve (what seems to me complicated but to many of you quite easy, I am sure) mathematical lines of code.

Here is one of the questions:

**Which of the following is output when the following code is run:**

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()

{

    int a = 300, b = 100, c = 100;

    if(a >= 400)

        b = 300;

    c = 200;

    printf("%d, %d, %d\n", a, b, c);

}
```

So I basically answered 300,100,100 (in the multiple choice answers), but the answer was 300,100,200. And (if I am being totally honest with you) if the option to choose 300,300,200 was there in the multiple choice I would have chosen that. I cant seem to understand why - in the result - only the value of c was changed?

Honestly, where this part of programming is concerned I am really struggling. I am determined to keep working hard on it though.

Any tips, or advice you guys have will be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards.

Comment: This line `c = 200;` tells you `c` changes.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Do not be discouraged. It is important for you to understand how statements in a program are executed, and how assignments work.

Comment: using a debugger will show you the execution of your program step-by-step. Useful even when it does not crash :)

Comment: The `if` has a condition `(a >= 400)` which controls the execution of the next _statement_, in this case `b = 300;`. Because what follows is another statement `c = 200;` and not the keyword `else`, that statement is always executed if/when reached.

Comment: Horrible coding style IMO not to have braces around the statement b=300 - suggest you get used using braces whenever there is an if or while statement.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My next question is then why is the value of b not changed in the result line? This is where I am having difficulty understanding. I read it like this: if a is equal or less than 400 (which it is at 300) then b is 300 and c is 200. The way I read it I apply the if statement variable changes to just b and c. Does that make sense? I am rambling now. :)

Comment: `if (a >= 400)` means "if `a` is larger than, or equal to, 400."  `a` is 300, so nothing happens in that `if` statement and its consequence.

Comment: You should read it as if `a` is `>= 400`, then assign `300` to `b`, otherwise skip it. Then, always assign `200` to `a`.

Comment: `void main` is bad, by the way. It should be `int main`.

Comment: `>` means "greater than", not "less than".

Comment: Thanks guys. I think my problem was that I was including the c = 200; line inside the if statement. It finally makes sense to me. Thank you all so much. :)

Comment: This exactly the reason why I dislike this if-notation without the braces: it can only create confusion and it will never be clearer than having the exact same thing *with* the braces. This is basically a trick question: "do yo know, that if we don't write the braces for an if-statement then the scope of the conditional block is only the single statement right after the if(..)".

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the code, `b` and `c` have values assigned since their initialization.

But `b` is changed if the condition `a >= 400` is true i.e. `b` is set to `200` if `300 >= 400` is true. Is that true? No. So, `b` is left unchanged.

200 is assigned to `c` regardless anything else in your code.

In summary, since the declarations of `a` (=300), `b`(=100), and `c`(=100):

`a` isn't changed at all.

`b` is changed on a condition. But since that condition is false, it's not changed either.

`c` is *always* changed (200 is assigned).

So, you can now work out why the answer is so?

Comment: Thank you for your time. You guys have helped me more than you know here. I was lost trying to figure that out. :)

Answer (score 3):

Execution proceeds line by line, and control branches as required.

Initially, the line with the initializations runs:

```
int a = 300, b = 100, c = 100;
```

At this point, the values are `a = 300`, `b = 100` and `c = 100`.

```
if(a >= 400)
    b = 300;
```

The if statement works as follows:

```
if(condition)
    then-statement;
```

If the `condition` is *true*, then the `then-statement` is executed. Otherwise, we skip it. In your example, we are testing to see if `a >= 400`, since `a` is 300 so far, `300 >= 400` is *not true*, so we skip the statement `b = 300`.

At this point, the values are *still* `a = 300`, `b = 100` and `c = 100` (since we did not change anything).

Finally, you have the line:

```
c = 200;
```

This statement is not guarded by an if, so it will *always* be executed. So, we update the value of `c` and set it to 200.

At this point, the values are `a = 300`, `b = 100` and `c = 200`.

So, when we get to the print statement, these are precisely the values that are printed out.

Comment: This is brilliant. So are you saying that the if statement only applies to the one following line (b=300;) then the c = 200 declaration is its own, new line and overrides the previous value declaration of c due to being further down the code? Simply put I was including the c = 200 line within the if statement itself and that was incorrect? :)

Comment: The if-statement applies to either a following line `if(condition) statement;`, or a following block (a bunch of lines wrapped in curly braces that looks like this: `if(condition) {statement-1; statement-2; ... statement-n;}`. In your example, since there are no curly braces after the `if`, it applies only to `b = 300` and **not** `c = 200`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 1):

The actual code seems to be like this.

```
 int a = 300, b = 100, c = 100;

    if(a >= 400)
       {
        b = 300;  
       }
    c = 200;

    printf("%d, %d, %d\n", a, b, c);
    }
```

if it is like this

```
 if(a >= 400)
        b = 300; 
        c= 200;
```

the very next line after if will be only part of it(if).
 Foreg:

```
int c=10;
if(c==10)
printf("iam 10");
else
printf("iam not 10");
```

its output will be 
 'iam 10'
 conditional statements(if, else..) without{} means its applicable for very next line only. this will be same for looping statements(for, while..) too.

Comment: Thank you very much. If it had of been written like that I would have understood it much sooner. I am used to seeing if statements with brackets. You guys are all awesome. :)

Answer (score 0):

You start off with:

```
int a = 300, b = 100, c = 100;
```

then if a(300) > 400 - something happens to b, it changes to 300.

```
if(a >= 400)

        b = 300;
```

BUT a is not > 400, so that part of the code does not get executed. 
so you are still at 300, 100, 100
Then, the last part of the code: `c = 200;`is independent. There is no condition that triggers it. c always changes to 200 when that line of code is reached. 
so now you have - a = 300, b = 100, c = 200